# How to make this code safe when accessing DLL?

Tags: c#, c, dll

To return arrays in C pointers needed. To clarify my question, I created a simple .c function and compiled as DLL and accessing it by C#. The C function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int* ReturnArray(int size) {

    int* arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); 

    arr[0] = 19;
    arr[1] = 18;
    arr[2] = 17;
    arr[3] = 16;
    arr[4] = 15;

    return arr;
}
```

On the C# side:

```
namespace ConsoleC2CSExample
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("array.dll", EntryPoint = "ReturnArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public unsafe static extern short* ReturnArray(int size);
        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arraySize = 5;

            short *ptr = ReturnArray(arraySize);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(*(ptr + i * sizeof(short)));              

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is as expected as follows:

[image]

I have two questions here.

1. How can this be done by not using unsafe mode?
2. And what are the dangers if any of using unsafe?

Comment: What happens if you import the function as `public static extern int[] ReturnArray(int size);` instead? (or `public static extern short[] ReturnArray(int size);` depending on word width)

Comment: Then I get compile error: "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context"

Comment: And regarding int short thing: I guess C# and C compilers have different size for int. I had to convert all int in C to short in C# side.

Comment: int ReturnArray(int[] array, int size), now the C# code can simply pass its own array, doesn't need a pointer and doesn't have a memory leak.

Comment: @HansPassant Imagine C side is an API and you are polling an array calling ReturnArray and a device is providing you arrays through C API. So this is not about using C# to construct arrays but calling C to return us an array at C# side. I hope I didn't misunderstand your comment.

Comment: You can't pass memory allocated with `malloc` (or `new`) from a `c` dll to `c#` and expect its lifetime to be managed - the memory is tracked by a memory manager local to the dll, and the CLR doesn't know how to manage or free it.

Comment: If you need to allocate an array inside the DLL and pass it to managed code, you'll need to use an allocator function that's accessible to both sides (so that the managed code can free the array). In these situations, the easiest solution is to allocate the array in managed code, pass it to the DLL to fill it with data and then free the array in managed code later - there's no allocation crossing the managed/unmanaged boundary.

Comment: @xxbbcc Would be great if you can show this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

C#/.NET is so-called managed code because it runs safely on the common language runtime (CLR). Whereas, C code is so-called unmanaged code.

The CLR ensures, that we will not suffer the typical problems known from C code (like buffer underflow, buffer overflow, ...) resulting in vulnerable code, crashing applications, unknown behavior, etc.

So the danger of using unsafe code is, that errors in your C library will probably terminate your entire C#/.NET application unexpectedly, causing you a lot of headache.

To get at least rid of the unsafe context within your C# code, you can try the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleC2CSExample
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("array.dll", EntryPoint = "ReturnArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr ReturnArray(int size);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arraySize = 5;

            IntPtr ptr = ReturnArray(arraySize);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr + i * sizeof(int)));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr + i * sizeof(int)));

Comment: I think your solution works. And how about  Console.WriteLine((ptr->GetType()).ToString()); How to use Marshal in that case?

Comment: Another pitfall. We need to be very careful about the size. `int` in C is 4 bytes wide, so we also have to use `int` respectively `Int32` in C# => `Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr + i * sizeof(int))`

Comment: @GNZ, I don't understand what you mean with `(ptr->GetType()).ToString()`. What would you expect as output?

Comment: I just wanted to see if we can also modify ptr->. You exchanged pointers with IntPtr such as *ptr became IntPtr ptr. I just wanted to know if we encounter and need to use -> operator how could we modify and use ptr-> in safe case. I saw this -> operator is mostly used in structs pointing to registers in C. I will receive a C API and want to use C#. Thats why Im trying to get into it. I might need to use some C API functions through .NET C#.

Comment: @GNZ Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-explicit-pinvoke-in-cpp-dllimport-attribute for more details on Interop.